# Running redis on MacOS - ping works without redis-server

Tags: redis

I have just installed redis on MacOS. I'm following through the standard intro process. It says that in order start the DB I should call

```
$ redis-server
```

It also says that in order to confirm the server is running I should do the following:

```
$ redis-cli ping
    PONG
```

I notice that I can ping the redis-cli as above and still get `PONG` back, even if I haven't executed `redis-server`. Does this mean that redis is running even if I don't exec `redis-server`?

If that is the case, how do I start and stop the local db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you did not say, I guess you installed **Redis** using **homebrew**.

You can check what services you have started with **homebrew** using:

```
brew services list
```

Then you can use:

```
brew services start redis
```

and:

```
brew services stop redis
```

Comment: Ah I see, yes I did do that. Does that mean that brew services is wholly  responsible for starting and stopping the db? In that case, what does calling `redis-server` do, if brew services has already started the db?

Comment: I have not tried that - but I guess the subsequent, manual attempt to start `redis-server` after `brew services` has already started it will result in it not starting as the network port will not be available for binding.